# How to improve efficiency of conditional code block in Markdown (Quarto) with Python?

Tags: python, plotly, markdown, quarto

I have a Markdown document with code blocks in different formats depending on the output format. Here is an example:

````
::: {.content-visible when-format="html"}

```{python}
# | label: fig-scores
fig = plot_scores(grammar_dict)
fig.show()  # html version
```

:::

::: {.content-visible when-format="docx"}

```{python}
# | label: fig-scores-docx
fig = plot_scores(grammar_dict)
plot_file = "figures/scores.png"
fig.write_image(plot_file)
display(Image(filename=plot_file))
```

:::

::: {.content-visible when-format="pdf"}

```{python}
# | label: fig-scores-latex
fig = plot_scores(grammar_dict)
plot_file = "figures/scores.png"
fig.write_image(plot_file)
# Display the image plot_file in LaTeX environment, scaled to fit text width
display(Latex(r"\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{" + plot_file + "}"))
```

:::
````

As you can see, each code block has a conditional attribute `{.content-visible when-format="html"}`, `{.content-visible when-format="docx"}`, or `{.content-visible when-format="pdf"}` to determine which block should be visible in which output format. These are necessary as the fig is created using `plotly`.

However, I feel like this could be more efficient. Is there a better way to write conditional code blocks in Markdown using Python, perhaps using a single code block that can output different formats depending on the desired output format? I tried using knitr (`is_html_output()`) in Python but couldn't make it work. So the conditional code blocks are a solution but they are not very efficient. Ideally, I would be able to call a function like `display_plots(fig)` that automatically sets the right fig based on the output format.

Thanks in advance!

Additional info:
Using Quarto and plotly.

Comment: Would it not be possible to use three `content-visible when-format` blocks at the start of the file that set a variable to three different values and/or define three variants of the same `display_plots()` function? Then further code blocks don't need to differentiate on the format anymore but they can just use the value of that variable or the defined function.

Comment: I was very hopeful about this but it seems that the conditional attribute doesn't prevent the code from executing. It just prevents it from being visible. While testing this, using three separate `when-format` blocks, all three versions still executed, and the last one overwrote the previous ones. This last was then used to `display_plots()` while rendering.